# Why am I unable to edit a price set?

Tags: price-sets

For some reason I timeout when I try to edit a price set. I have maybe 30 custom price sets or so (mostly because I have had this problem for awhile, so I have to create a new price set with every new contribution page (if I want to modify the price set in any way, like, for instance, change its expiry date). This happens no matter whether the price set is in use, cloned or created from scratch without any connection to a contribution page or an event registration. I just get a spinning CiviCRM triangle of death. Nothing gets saved.

I am using 4.6.26 on D7.

P.S. I am able to make the changes to the tables. The only change I need to make is to expiration fields. However, I don't see why I shouldn't be able to make those changes from within the regular edit screens in civicrm. Something is definitely wrong somewhere.

P.P.S. I just discovered I cannot edit profiles either. This must mean there is something wrong generally, perhaps the server or permissions. There is a workaround for the profiles which is to use the editor function in the "list view" for the profile. I can click on several of the fields to edit, but not in the general edit screen (accessible by clicking the "edit" link in the far right column). Whatever, maybe someone else has solved this issue?

Comment: You may have already tried this, but if the window that you do the Edit in is a popup, then instead of clicking Edit to get the popup, right click and open in new Tab. Then there is more of a chance that you will see any errors being generated. May not apply in your case but it can be useful to know.

Comment: What a great idea! Just tried it though, and all I got was this: "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment," when I hit "Save"! Not too informative.

Comment: Have you checked your drupal (or whatever) logs?

Answer (score 1):

You may have already tried this, but if the window that you do the Edit in is a popup, then instead of clicking Edit to get the popup, right click and open in new Tab. Then there is more of a chance that you will see any errors being generated. May not apply in your case but it can be useful to know.

(Decided the comment i made was worth posting as an Answer.)

Comment: Thanks for this, Pete. See my comment above. Any other ideas? It is really a pain. I can re-edit everything else (I think?), email drafts, events, contribution pages, etc., in my instance, just not these (Profiles and Price Sets). Annoying. Could it have anything to do with the fact that these are pop-up style edit screens? What would cause that?

Comment: if you are side stepping the pop up then no i don't think that is the factor